# Cannot use pip install pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

when using pip install pandas
An error occurs as follows:

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.5.2.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "d:\py\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "d:\py\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "d:\py\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
        File "d:\py\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
        File "d:\py\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\zijie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kqsd82rz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import Distribution
        File "C:\Users\zijie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kqsd82rz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 47, in <module>
          from . import _entry_points
        File "C:\Users\zijie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kqsd82rz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_entry_points.py", line 43, in <module>
          def validate(eps: metadata.EntryPoints):
      AttributeError: module 'importlib.metadata' has no attribute 'EntryPoints'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

py:3.10.0
os:windows11

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thanks!

I tried several times but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried pip install wheel before pip install pandas?

Comment: 1. Try `pip uninstall pandas` 
2. Make sure you are up-to-date on pip
3. Perhaps try a virtual environment (e.g. conda)
4. Never hurts to try the good ol' `python3.10 -m pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

pip3 install pandas?

Comment: 1) pip uninstall pandas
2) pip install pandas

if that doesn't work...
3) pip install pandas --user

if that doesn't work....
4) pip install --upgrade pip
and retry...

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering a question on SO! A little feedback - this answer could as easily be provided as a comment - leaving formal "Answers" for "solutions" that other searchers for similar questions would find useful. Thanks again.